# req.session undefined with Redis/Express

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I switched from memorystore to using Redis and I also use MongoDB locally.

Similar posts that I have read are not relevant or helpfull.
Basicly, if the router function try's to set a value to req.session the node app shuts down.

I am new to Redis, so maybe it is something obvious that I don't see?

```
// in app
var app = express();
var cookieParser = express.cookieParser('secret');
app.configure(function () {
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(cookieParser);
  app.use(express.session({secret: 'secret', store: othermodule.getSessionStore()})); 

// othermodule
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(express);  
var sessionStore = new RedisStore({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 6379,
    db: 2,
    pass: 'RedisPASS'});
```

thanks

Comment: Try removing the pass and also check if your redis host/ports are correct

Comment: do I also need a client from redis.createclient? I am reading documentation for connect-redis, host should be localhost for the machine I think

Comment: I used to give client in option, never tried without it. Gave the same options to the client.

Comment: that worked,thanks!Do you know why ommitting the pass makes it work?Can you post in an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the password in your options you pass to RedisStore.

If you want you can require the clients to give a password when connecting. But by default no password is required for clients to connect. If no password is required and you give a password, the client will try authenticating using the given password which will cause a connection failure. The fallback to using no password is not allowed at the client. Because of which you were getting session as undefined.

See [here](http://redis.io/topics/config) and [here](http://redis.io/topics/security) for configuring passwords.